# Making a stacked bar chart with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm stuck on how to get a stacked bar chart that shows the yes and no votes on a ballot measure in this election data. Here's the dataframe I'm using and the code I have so far that shows just the no votes

```
pre <- c("Del Mar Heights","Rancho Penasquitos","La Jolla","Mira Mesa","Miramar")
yes_on_b <- c(7533,16607,6243,10200,443)
no_on_b <- c(8477,20478,8406,10054,356)

ggplot(measure_b_result, aes(pre,no_on_b)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="steelblue")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the data in long format which will make it easier to plot. You may use `pivot_longer` to do that.

```
library(tidyverse)

measure_b_result %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -pre) %>%
  ggplot(aes(pre,value, fill = name)) +
  geom_col() + 
  labs(x = "Pre", y = "Number of votes", fill = "Type")
```

[image]